# Using Javascipt to Create SelectList Dependencies in a VF Page

Tags: apex, soql, dependent-picklist

I am trying to code create dependent Picklists out of 2 apex:SelectLists on a Visualforce page.

I have a junction Object called Service_Transaction_Type__c that creates a many-to-many relationship between two other custom objects (Service_Offering__c and Transaction_Type__c). I am also working with another custom object that has a rather long name (referred to as CustomObject__c here). CustomObject__c is a junction Object between Service_Offering__c and Account.

The first list is below as well as the code in the custom controller that populates it:

VF PAGE COMOPNENT:

```
<apex:outputLabel style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana ">Health Plan</apex:outputLabel><br/> 
<apex:selectList id="hpList" size="1" value="{!cs.Health_Plan__c}" label="" styleClass="myField">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!SNANAMatch}"/>
</apex:selectList>
<br/><br/>
```

CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
           User u = [SELECT Id, ContactId, FirstName FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

           Contact c = [SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id =:u.ContactId];

           Account a = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :c.AccountId];

           List<CustomObject__c> sn = [SELECT Id, Name, Service_Offering__r.Display_Name__c FROM CustomObject__c WHERE Account__c = :a.Id]; 

           List<Service_Offering__c> serviceList = new List<Service_Offering__c>();

    public Set<SelectOption> getSNANAMatch(){

        Set<SelectOption> DeDupedHPList = new Set<SelectOption>();
               DeDupedHPList.add(New SelectOption('Not Health Plan Related', 'Not Health Plan Related'));  

        List<String> HealthPlanStrings = New List<String>();

        for (CustomObject__c snanas : sn){

        HealthPlanStrings.add(snanas.Service_Offering__r.Display_Name__c);

        }

        HealthPlanStrings.sort();

        for (String plan : HealthPlanStrings){
        deDupedHPList.add(new SelectOption(plan, plan));

        }

            return DeDupedHPList;

    }
```

As a result, the first selectlist is an alphabetized and de-duped.  list of Health Plans associated with an account with "Not Health Plan Related" being the first option before that alphabetized list. This first list is working just fine.
Each health plan has its own set of Transaction Types. In my second paragraph above, I have explained how I am creating this many-to-many relationship.

I am trying many different combinations of javascript and apex:actionFunction to try and get it run a method called getTransactionTypes() in the controller whenever a new element is selected on the health plans list. The goal here is to get the second selectList (Transaction Types) to only display the associated TRX types for the selected plan.

**I do not need the function run through all the records, I am just trying to get it to run "onSelect" from the first SelectList (Health Plan List)**

I have a placeholder function that I am running to try and test this. It does not create and push the new selectlist, but I just want this function to be called every time a new option is selected on the Health Plans List. Below is that function:

SECOND CONTROLLER METHOD:

```
Set<SelectOption> TRXTypes = new Set<SelectOption>();
        TRXTypes.add(New SelectOption('Not Transaction Related', 'Not Transaction Related')); 



    String chosenPlan = '';

    if (cs.Health_Plan__c != 'Not Transaction Related'){
        chosenPlan = 'argument1';
    }
    else{
        chosenPlan = 'argument2';
    }
    TRXtypes.add(new SelectOption(chosenPlan, chosenPlan));

    return TRXtypes;
}
```

And here is the second Selectlist component on the Visualforce page:

```
<apex:outputLabel style="font-size:11px; font-family:Verdana ">Transaction Type</apex:outputLabel><br/>
<apex:actionFunction   action="{!getTransactionTypes}"  name="getTransactionTypes"/>

<apex:selectList id="trxList" size="1" value="{!cs.Transaction_Type__c}" label="" styleClass="myField">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!TransactionTypes}"/>
</apex:selectList>
<br/><br/>
```

Additonally, I have tried a jquery function to have it run this method. I have tried adding the method to the "onSelect" attribute in the health plans list but this did not work either

Any input on where I could go to resolve this would go a long way.

Thanks,
CP